# Django admin panel can not set valid choice when choices are enum.Enum

Tags: django, enums, django-admin, models

I use enum.Enum as choices for field language.

I can create a book by `b = Book(title="Some Title", language=LanguageChoice.EN)`.

And query by `books = Book.objects.filter(languge=LanguageChoice.EN)`.

**However**, when I want to create new books at admin panel, it says `Select a valid choice. LanguageChoice.EN is not one of the available choices.`.

Django has [ability to serialize enum.Enum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#migrations) since 1.10. So how should admin panel work? Thanks.

```
from enum import Enum
from django.db import models


class LanguageChoice(Enum):
    DE = "German"
    EN = "English"
    CN = "Chinese"
    ES = "Spanish"


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=[(tag, tag.value) for tag in LanguageChoice]  
    )
```

Comment: The ability to serialise them doesn't imply the ability to use them as choice values.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem. Rewrite your `Book` model as the following, and notice the change in the choices line.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=[(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in LanguageChoice]  
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your Django model as

```
class LanguageChoice(Enum):
    DE = "German"
    EN = "English"
    CN = "Chinese"
    ES = "Spanish"

    @classmethod
    def all(self):
        return [LanguageChoice.DE, LanguageChoice.EN, LanguageChoice.CN, LanguageChoice.ES]


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=[(tag.value, tag.name) for tag in LanguageChoice.all()]  
    )
```

Comment: Enum doesn't have `all()`.

Comment: Just changing `(tag, tag.value)` to `(tag.name, tag.value)` should be enough. The rest of the changes aren't needed.

Answer (score -4):

I changed `(tag,tag.value)` to `(tag.value,tag)` and it worked.